# Message delimitation in TCP communication

Tags: sockets, security, tcp

I am a newbie to networks and in particular TCP (I have been fooling a bit with UDP, but that's it).
I am developing a simple protocol based on exchanging messages between two endpoints. Those messages need to be certified, so I implemented a cryptographic layer that takes care of that. However, while UDP has a sound definition of a packet that constitutes the minimum unit that can get transferred at a time, the TCP protocol (as far as my understanding goes) is completely stream oriented.

Now, this puzzles me a bit. When exchanging messages, how can I tell where one starts and the other one ends? In principle, I can obviously communicate fixed length messages or first communicate the size of each message in some header. However, this can be subject to attacks: while of course it is going to be impossible to distort or determine the content of the communication, the above technique would make it easy to completely disrupt my communication just by adding a single byte in the middle.

Say that I need to transfer a message 1234567 bytes long. First of all, I communicate 4 bytes with an integer representing the size of the message. Okay. Then I start sending out the actual message. That message gets split in several packets, which get separately received. Now, an attacker just sends in an additional packet, faking it as if it was part of the conversation. It can just be one byte long: this completely destroys any synchronization mechanism I have implemented! The message has a spurious byte in the middle, and it doesn't successfully get decoded. Not only that, the last byte of the first message disrupts the alignment of the second message and so on: the connection is destroyed, and with a simple, simple attack! How likely and feasible is this attack anyway?

So I am wondering: what is the maximum data unit that can be transferred at once? I understand that to a call to send doesn't correspond a call to receive: the message can be split in different chunks. How can I group the packets together in some way so that I know that they get packed together? Is there a way to define an higher level message that gets reconstructed and aligned all together and triggers a single call to a receive-like function? If not, what other solutions can I find to keep my communication re-alignable even in presence of an attacker?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2385.txt is quite relevant to what you describe. (And several operating system support TCP-MD5 signatures, usually enabled with some calls to setsockopt() )

Comment: 1) TCP has sequence numbers; you cannot *inject* a few bytes into the stream without the communication getting messed up. 2) There are no message bounderies; you'll have to implement your own bounderies in an application level protocol, either by using fixed-length messages, or by prefixing the *messages* by a header (what to expect) or by delimiting them by an *end-of-message* character, such as `\n`.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually you _probably_ can inject a few bytes into the stream as an active MITM attacker can modify the SEQs/ACKs as well. And for certain network stacks it is even easier because of their (mis)handling of the [out-of-band data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Out-of-band_data).

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is difficult to control the way the OS divides the stream into TCP packets (The RFC defining TCP protocol states that TCP stack should allow the clients to force it to send buffered data by using *push function*, but it does not define how many packets this should generate. After all the attacker can modify any of them).

And these TCP packets can get divided even more into IP fragments during their way through the network (which can be opted-out by a 'Do not fragment' IP flag -- but this flag can cause that your packets are not delivered at all).

I think that your problem is not about *introducing packets into a stream protocol*, but about *securing it*.

IPSec could be very beneficial in your scenario, as it operates on the network layer.

It provides integrity for every packet sent, so any modification on-the-wire gets detected and the invalid packets are dropped. In case of TCP the dropped packets get re-transmitted automatically.

(Almost) everything is done automatically by the OS -- so yo do not need to worry about it (and make mistakes doing so).

The confidentiality can be assured as well (with the same advantage of not re-inventing the wheel).

IPSec should provide you a reliable transport protocol ontop of which you can use whatever framing format you like.

Another alternative is using SSL/TLS on top of TCP session which is less robust (as it does close the whole connection on integrity error).

Comment: "Basically it is difficult to control the way the OS divides the stream into TCP packets". It is impossible. TCP is entitled to to do that any way it likes. It is a byte-stream protocol. The PSH flag which implements the 'push' function applies to the current segment and everything preceding it. Nothing undefined about that. And in any case it's obsolete.

Comment: @EJP Definitely you can control it (i.e. embedded systems, raw sockets) but is is difficult :)

Comment: @EJP and _push function_ does not define _how_ the stack divides the stream into packets (that was meant by the undefined).

Comment: It is possible for the OS to control it, of course. Not if you aren't the OS. We are discussing TCP, not raw sockets. The statement 'the push function does not define how the stack divides the stream into packets' is basically meaningless. The 'push function' *is* a *single bit flag* and it is already *inside* a segment.

Comment: @EJP The statement _TCP stack should allow the clients to force it to send buffered data by using push function_ was meant, that clients should be able to force the TCP stack to **send** the data (on the **sending side** as an **outgoing buffering** might be taking place). See [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-4) (the paragraph starting with _"Sometimes users need to be sure that all the data they have submitted to the TCP has been transmitted"_). Usually this happens at `flush()`.

Comment: The PSH TCP flag you are talking about is a notification to the **receiving side** to pass the data to the application (as **input buffering** might be taking place). Disclaimer: I am not that much into TCP, but I read the RFC carefully some year ago and this is my understanding of it. Hope this discussion does not bother you (I am here to learn). Thank you!

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. The PUSH TCP flag *you* are talking about, and that *you* introduced to the discussion, is *both* a notification to the receiving side to push the data into the application, which is meaningless in the BSD sockets API, and a notification to the sending side to send it, as per your own quotation. `flush()` does not ensure that all data submitted has been transmitted: it flushes application buffers into the socket send buffer. Your point remains obscure. If you are not 'that much into TCP' it is difficult to understand why you are answering questions about it.

Comment: Dear @EJP, I meant exactly the same as is written [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPImmediateDataTransferPushFunction-2.htm). Especially the last paragraph. But you are definitely right -- I am not answering questions about tcp. I am answering questions about security. Best wishes to you...

Answer (score 0):

> *Now, an attacker just sends in an additional packet, faking it as if it was part of the conversation. It can just be one byte long: this completely destroys any synchronization mechanism I have implemented!*

Thwarting such an injection problem is dealt with by securing the stream. Create an encrypted stream and send your packets through that.

Of course the encrypted stream itself then has this problem; its messages can be corrupted. But those messages have secure integrity checks. The problem is detected, and the connection can be torn down and re-established to resynchronize it.

Also, some fixed-length synchronizing/framing bit sequence can be used between messages: some specific bit pattern.  It doesn't matter if that pattern occurs inside messages by accident, because we only ever specifically look for that pattern when things go wrong (a corrupt message is received), otherwise we skip that sequence. If a corrupt message is received, we then receive bytes until we see the synchronizing pattern, and assume that whatever follows it is the start of a message (length followed by payload). If *that* fails, we repeat the process. When we receive a correct message, we reply to the peer, which will re-transmit anything we didn't get.

> *How likely and feasible is this attack anyway?*

TCP connections are identified by four items: the source and destination IP, and source and destination port number.  The attacker has to fake a packet which matches your stream in these four identifiers, and sneak that packet past all the routers and firewalls between that attacker and the receiving machine.  The attacker also has to be in the right ballpark with regard to the TCP sequence number.

Basically, this is next to impossible for an attacker C to perpetrate against endpoints A and B which are both distant from C on the network. The fake source IP will be rejected long before C is able to reach its destination.  It's more plausible as an inside job (which includes malware): C is close to A and B.